# Getting four times the power by arranging four resistors

Tags: power, resistors, circuit-design, resistance

If I'm given four resistors of value R and power rating P (each resistor dissipates up to P), what are ways I can arrange these resistors so that my circuit has a power of 4P and resistance of R?

One way I have right now is two pairs in series and connect those two series pairs in parallel.

Another way I though might work is putting all four in series since P = V^2/R, so if it's 4R on the bottom, would the power be 4P?

Comment: Write down the fraction and try to do the math. Basically, you can introduce one redundant/dysfunctional connection, or skip that.

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is for the total resistance to equal R then you can't put them all in series as that would give you 4R.

You're correct by putting two series pairs in parallel, each series pair is 2R, paralleling two of those would give you 2R/2 = R. The other way to do it is to put two parallel pairs in series. Each parallel pair would be R/2, putting two of those in series would give you 2*(R/2) = R. In both cases the current would divide equally between the resistors giving you a power rating of 4P.